# How to force QueryRoots to fire on Xamarin app after first launch, storage provider

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, document-provider

I am trying to implement a Xamarin storage provider as per the example here.

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/StorageProvider

The issue is that I want the user to log in before I render the root folders.

The method used to query the roots is the following:

`public override ICursor QueryRoots(string[] projection)`

This is called when the app first launches, but does not seem to be called subsequently.

If I log in (hard coded credentials) straight away, this works fine.  However if I open the app so I can add some login details manually then this does not get called again and therefore does not re-render the correct roots.

Has anyone got any ideas how I force Android to re-call this method again to refresh this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to call the below method to notify the system that the status of our roots has changed

```
 Activity.ContentResolver.NotifyChange (DocumentsContract.BuildRootsUri (AUTHORITY), null, false);
```

you could see the explanation here https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/0b301e8fd2da65ff442b5f1ed236c73ba3b963c2/StorageProvider/MyCloudFragment.cs#L66.

Comment: Thank you, that is great this is just what I need.